# How to modify/update column values on a condition in Pydatatable?

Tags: python, py-datatable

In pydatatable, I'm trying to modify a column values specifying a condition in i i.e `DT[i=="text", j="some"]`

**sample DT:**

```
py_DT= dt.Frame({'crossing':['ABC','A','B','B','A','A','ABC'],
                 'total' :[2,4,5,6,8,10,12]})
```

Here i would like to replace crossing value `'ABC'` with `'A'` only, for that i have written a below sample code,

**Attempt 1:**

```
py_DT[f.crossing=="ABC", f.crossing=="A"]
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
py_DT[f.crossing=="ABC", update(f.crossing=="A")]
```

None of these attempts were worked out, is there any other way to get it solved? Could you please write to me how to update a column value as per the said requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```py
py_DT[f.crossing == 'ABC', f.crossing] = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to replace all 'ABC' values, right? In that case you could use `df.str.replace()`:

```
py_DT['crossing'].str.replace("ABC", "A")
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. that can be OK in pandas dataframe. But i wanted to do it in pydatatable way.

Comment: I've looked at the documentation for [datatable](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html) and couldn't find anything other than Pandas to replace. I'd recommend just converting it to a Pandas dataframe like they do [here at the replace() part.](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/frame.html)

Comment: Yes, the pandas workaround can be worked out and i'm just awaiting for a response from pydatatable team members or other who could come across this situation earlier, lets wait and see.