# how to replace whole column values on dt.datatable on python?

Tags: python, datatable

i have a datatable like this one :

```
status
▪▪▪▪
0   abc
1   abc
2   ddd
3   aaa
```

and I want to replace to :

***convert the small letter ot capital letter***

```
status
▪▪▪▪
0   ABC
1   ABC
2   DDD
3   AAA
```

**how to use `datatable` package to do this one?**

i know if my table is dataframe in pandas,
I can use:

```
data['status'] = data['status'].apply(lambda x: x.upper())
```

Comment: what is `datatable `?

Comment: OK. got it: https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59543028/how-to-modify-update-column-values-on-a-condition-in-pydatatable

Comment: sorry guys 
i want to convert the small letter to capital letter

Comment: Isn't pandas more popular ?

Comment: yes, but datatable will more fast in reading data

Answer (score 2):

can use this way:

```
data['status'] = dt.Frame([value.upper() for value in data['status'].to_list()[0]])
```

I got the answer from github:
https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues/2649